# SVN with Apache authenticate against OS user accounts

Tags: apache, svn, apache2

I am starting to look into configuring an SVN server using Apache2 and mod_dav_svn on Red Hat Linux.  I want Apache to handle authenticating the users that access the repository.  Is there a way to have Apache authenticate against the user credentials maintained by the OS?  This way I can allow all of my users on the server to use the same account to access SVN and to login to the system via SSH.

Previously our SVN server was hosted on a Windows server and we were able to use `AuthType SSPI` to perform our authentication against the Windows Active Directory server which will no longer be available to us. (Note: this is a restriction due to our network security and is not with my control)

Comment: You can still authenticate against the AD server from a Red Hat box using Apache...

Comment: I suppose I should clarify that the reason I cannot access the AD server is due to where within our network the server will be located.  For security reasons it won't be able to access that segment of the network.  Will clarify in my question.

Comment: So only the *client* OS has a means to verify the credentials, not the server?

Comment: My hope was that there would be a way to authenticate using the same credentials as the local user accounts we have on the server.  That way there wasn't a need maintain the local user account password and a separate password file for Apache authentication.  The authentication would still be happening on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately the solution I found to this problem was to configure [mod-authnz_external](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) to work with [pwauth](http://code.google.com/p/pwauth/).  Following the instructions on those two sites seems to have resulted in a working solution.